# How do you set the schema name for sequences at deploy time when using JPA?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, persistence

For security reasons, our oracle db objects normally belong to a different schema than the logged in user. Eg. tables are in xx_core and the user we log in is xx_app_yy .
In my persistence.xml I define a orm file so that I can specify the schema name at deploy time eg.:
    `<mapping-file>xx_schema_orm.xml</mapping-file>`

Then in the xx_schema_orm.xml I can define the object-owning-schema eg.:

```
<persistence-unit-metadata>
  <persistence-unit-defaults>
    <schema>xx_core</schema>
  </persistence-unit-defaults>
</persistence-unit-metadata>
```

This works great for tables, but I can't find the equivalent for sequences. It tries to use the sequence without the schema name and then I get an exception:

```
2010-10-14 03:04:05,423:DEBUG   could not get next sequence value [select xx_SEQ.nextval from dual]     - org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:145)
```

I've tried to set the schema name as part of the sequence name for a generator in the xx_schema_orm.xml, but could not get it working eg.:

```
<sequence-generator name="xx_SEQ_GEN"
sequence-name="xx_core.xx_SEQ"/>
```

Workarounds I may try:

- make a database SYNONYM for the sequences in the user's schema.
- stop using sequences and use some other way to generate ids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JPA 2.0:

- the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation and the equivalent `sequence-generator` element **do allow to specify a `schema` (and `catalog`) name**.
- the **`schema` subelement should be honored by sequence generators** as well.

But this doesn't apply to JPA 1.0.

I'll just quote the sections about the `schema` subelement to illustrate the differences (other relevant sections are mentioned in the references below). From the JPA 2.0 specification:

> #### 12.2.1.1 schema
>
> **The `schema` subelement applies to all** entities, tables, secondary
>   tables, join tables, collection
>   tables, table generators, and
>   **sequence generators** in the persistence unit.
>
> The `schema` subelement is overridden
>   by any `schema` subelement of the
>   `entity-mappings` element; any `schema`
>   element explicitly specified in the
>   `Table` or `SecondaryTable` annotation
>   on an entity or any `schema` attribute
>   on any `table` or `secondary-table`
>   subelement defined within an `entity`
>   element; any `schema` element
>   explicitly specified in a
>   `TableGenerator` annotation or
>   `table-generator` subelement; any
>   schema element explicitly specified in
>   a `SequenceGenerator` annotation or
>   `sequence-generator` subelement; any
>   `schema` element explicitly specified
>   in a `JoinTable` annotation or
>   `join-table` subelement; and any
>   schema element explicitly specified in
>   a `CollectionTable` annotation or
>   `collection-table` subelement.

From the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 10.1.1.1 schema
>
> **The `schema` subelement applies** to all
>   entities, **table generators**, and join
>   tables in the persistence unit.
>
> The `schema` subelement is overridden
>   by any `schema` subelement of the
>   `entity-mappings` element; any
>   `schema` element explicitly specified
>   in the `Table` or `SecondaryTable`
>   annotation on an entity or any schema
>   attribute on any `table` or
>   `secondary-table` subelement defined
>   within an `entity` element; any
>   `schema` element explicitly specified
>   in a `TableGenerator` annotation or
>   `table-generator` subelement; and any
>   `schema` element explicitly specified
>   in a `JoinTable` annotation or
>   `join-table` subelement.

So, unless your provider offers some specific extensions, my suggestions are:

- Upgrade to JPA 2.0 if possible and using the `schema` subelement will do the trick ~or~
- Use a `TableGenerator` if you have to stick with JPA 1.0 ~or~
- Use an alias if this is possible (I don't know).

#### References

- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - Section 9.1.37 "SequenceGenerator Annotation"
  - Section 10.1.1.1 "schema"
  - Section 12.2.2.5 "sequence-generator"
- JPA 2.0 Specification

  - Section 11.1.44 "SequenceGenerator Annotation"
  - Section 12.2.1.1 "schema"
  - Section 12.2.2.5 "sequence-generator"

Comment: Wow,thanks Pascal! I'm stuck with JPA1, and I don't like the idea of a table generator, but fortunately I managed to make a synonym for the user in oracle eg. `create synonym xx_app_yy.xx_SEQ for xx_core.xx_SEQ;`

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for asking the obvious, but you have granted select privilege on the sequences to the user that's trying to select from them, right?

Comment: Yes. the query it is trying to run is wrong as can be seen above "select xx_SEQ.nextval from dual" should be "select xx_core.xx_SEQ.nextval from dual"