# How to generate a sequence in a specific schema with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'd like to autogenerate a `sequence` using `hibernate`:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "my_entity", schema = "test")
    public static class MyEntity {    
        private static final String SEQUENCE = "my_seq";

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQUENCE)
        @SequenceGenerator(name = SEQUENCE, sequenceName = SEQUENCE, schema = "test")
        private Long id;
     }
```

Result: the sequence is generated in schema `public`. Why?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Probably similar question/answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937986/how-do-you-set-the-schema-name-for-sequences-at-deploy-time-when-using-jpa

Comment: @MickMnemonic `postgres` 9.4 and Jpa 2.1